# Simplify bash if statement with or operators

Tags: bash, scripting

```
isCat()  [[ $word = "cat" ]]
isDog()  [[ $word = "dog" ]]
isFish() [[ $word = "fish" ]]
isAny()  { if isCat || isDog || isFish; then return 0; else return 1; fi }
```

I would like to simplify the 'isAny' function to something like:

```
isAny() [[ isCat || isDog || isFish ]]
```

but I'm not finding out how to. The above attempt is incorrect because 'isAny' is true when all the other functions evaluate to false. I'm using these functions in this way:

```
if isCat; then
  echo "cat"
fi
if isAny; then
  echo "any"
fi
```

Comment: All-caps function names are extremely unusual from a stylistic perspective. Functions define commands, and commands are not conventionally all-caps on UNIX.

Comment: `[[ IS_CAT || IS_DOG || IS_FISH ]]`, by the way, is exactly equivalent to `[[ -n IS_CAT || -n IS_DOG || -n IS_FISH ]]`, or `[ -n "IS_CAT" ] || [ -n "IS_DOG" ] || [ -n "IS_FISH" ]`: it checks whether the string "IS_CAT" is non-empty (or the string "IS_DOG" is non-empty, or the string "IS_FISH" is non-empty) -- always true (since `IS_CAT` is a six-character string by definition, and thus *never* a zero-character/empty string), and a completely different thing from running a function named `IS_CAT`.

Comment: I'm using all caps because it makes it much easier to see and thus read in my script. I should have used the naming convention for the purpose of this question...

Comment: There's readability-to-you, and there's readability-to-people-who've-internalized-POSIX-conventions. To folks who've internalized conventions, an all-caps symbol means that you're referring to a variable with special meaning to the shell or operating system -- see fourth paragraph of [the POSIX spec on environment variables](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap08.html), referring to their naming conventions, while keeping in mind that regular shell variables share a namespace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason

```
isAny() [[ isCat || isDog || isFish ]]
```

...is always true, even if the functions all return false, is that it's checking whether `"isCat"`, `"isDog"`, and `"isFish"` are non-empty strings -- which of course they always are -- rather than running them as functions.

---

If you're literally trying to do a comparison against several fixed tokens, a `case` statement is the conventional (and POSIX-compliant) way to do this:

```
case $word in
  cat|dog|fish) return 0;;
  *) return 1;;
esac
```

That said, if this was a nonliteral example:

```
isAny() { isCat || isDog || isFish; }
```

...is the easiest way to write your function. Because it's not in `[[ ]]`, it's actually running shell commands (your defined functions), rather than interpreting content as extended-`test` syntax.

Answer (score 2):

A shell function will return the exit status of the last command it ran. Thus…

```
IS_ANY() { IS_CAT || IS_DOG || IS_FISH; }
```

will do the trick.